# The first fragment added to the adapter is not displayed. The second one is displayed perfectly. Databinding works, tried without ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

When adding fragments to the adapter, the first TariffUserAndQuestFragment is not displayed, everything is fine with the second TariffOurServicesFragment. I tried swapping them anyway TariffUserAndQuestFragment is empty. Checked without ViewPagerTariffAdapter(just using DataBinding) everything is displayed correctly)

MainActivity

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerTariffAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerTariffAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new TariffUserAndQuestFragment(this, tariffs), "Тарифы");
        adapter.addFragment(new TariffOurServicesFragment(this, services), Strings.isguest ? "Акции" : "Услуги");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

TariffUserAndQuestFragment

```
public class TariffUserAndQuestFragment extends Fragment {

    Context context;
    List<Tarif> list;

    public TariffUserAndQuestFragment(Context context, List<Tarif> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_tarifs,
                container, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

        if (!Strings.isguest)
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new TariffUserAdapterBinding(list));
        else
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new TariffGuestAdapterBinding(list));
        return recyclerView;
    }
}
```

TariffOurServicesFragment

```
public class TariffOurServicesFragment extends Fragment {

    Context context;
    List<OurService> list;

    public TariffOurServicesFragment(Context context, List<OurService> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_tarifs,
                container, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new OurServiceBindingAdapter(list));
        return recyclerView;
    }
}
```

ViewPagerTariffAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerTariffAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerTariffAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
}
```